# error when opening Aptana Studio 3

Tags: aptana

I've tried running Aptana Studio on OS X and when it runs I get this message

> The JVM shared library
>   "**/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Content/Home/bin/../jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib**"
>   does not contain the **JNI_CreateJavaVM** symbol.

How do I fix this?

Comment: same error here with jdk 7 on Yosemite

Comment: if my answer helps you , please mark it as the right answer

Answer (score 6):

you just need to update your java JDK

you can use apple's  support site :

https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

or you can use the latest version from Java official site  :

https://www.java.com/en/

then restart the device and enjoy Aptana

Comment: I downloaded Apple's Java and it seems to be working now. I am on El Capitan.

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same error. It occurred under 1.7.0_65 so I upgrade to 1.8.0_11 and the issue persisted. I found a blog which describes a similar error with opening eclipse ([Eclipse does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM](http://burrsutter.blogspot.com/2013/12/eclipse-does-not-contain.html)) which suggests the issue is with the newer version of 64bit java and eclipse. Since Aptana is partly based on eclipse I figured it could be a similar issue so I went to the console log and found this...

```
8/13/14 4:40:49.756 PM AptanaStudio3[413]: Error loading /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib:  dlopen(/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib, 265): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

The error stating wrong architecture leads me to think there is truth to the blogger's findings. I would assume that you can always load an older version of Java JDK or run a 32bit version but it would all depend on if you really want to go that far.

Update: To test installed Java JRE 1.6 and that seemed to work ([Apple Java for OS X 2014-001](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572)).

```
Host OS: Mac OS X
OS Version: 10.9.4
OS Arch: x86

JRE Version: 1.6.0_65
JRE Vendor: Apple Inc.
JRE Home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

Aptana Studio 3 Version: 3.6.0.201407100658
```

Comment: To test I rolled back to Java JRE 1.6 and that seemed to work. Update in original post.

Answer (score 2):

You may be missing a Java update from Apple.

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Answer (score 2):

The link to the "update" from Apple is a very old version of Java. Even Apple discourages users from installing it due to security vulnerabilities.

It is odd that Aptana 3 runs on Windows 8.1 64-bit and Server 2012 64-bit with the latest version of Oracle's JRE but not on OS X Yosemite.

But after 30+ years as a software developer I should know better than to expect cross platform products to function properly.

As tempted as you may be to run this product with an outdated JRE, do yourself a favor and just find another editor. A compromised system isn't worth it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a x64 system, you MUST install a x86 version of JRE/JDK such is described here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Setting_up_Studio-section-37540095_SettingupStudio-OracleJDK

Comment: The link you provided only say that the 32 bit JDK is required for Windows. But it seems Aptana on OSX requires this version as well. I was able to fix the problem by using the link *AdrianSong* and *Frank Rizzo* provided.